# Who is the woman in the post credit of "Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In the post-credit scene of *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* a mysterious woman appears and tells him that

> He has caused an incursion.

Who is this woman?

Comment: It's Charlize Theron, duh!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The woman is [Clea](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Clea). In the comics she resides within the Dark Dimension, which seems to hold true to the MCU, and is Strange's main love interest. She also becomes Sorceress Supreme for a time while Strange is dead. Writer Michael Waldron gives some insight into the inclusion of the character in an interview below:

> **io9: Speaking of that, incursions are also our window to the introduction of Clea, played by Charlize Theron. Tell me about how and when that idea got put into place as the end credits scene.**
>
> **Waldron:** We knew that we wanted to introduce Clea. She’s Strange’s great love in the comics and it was felt to me like Strange wasn’t at the point at the start of our movie where he was ready to meet the love of his life. It felt like we had to close the loop with he and Christine Palmer. And so after she gives him her wisdom to not be afraid of loving someone, then it felt like we were right to tease what could be eventually with he and Clea.
>
> <sub>[Gizmodo, *Doctor Strange 2*'s Writer Breaks Down the Movie's Biggest Spoilers](https://gizmodo.com/doctor-strange-2-spoilers-interview-marvel-mordo-wanda-1848906359)</sub>

Comment: The absence the hero's traditional love interest, Clea, from the Doctor Strange movies has been my biggest problem with them.

Comment: @Buzz Feige has explained why they went with Christine over Clea originally before: _"We wanted a grounded character. We wanted a character that was a connection to Strange’s life in New York City, in the normal world. Somebody that could be his anchor to the real world, to his present in the beginning of the film, and by the time he re-encounters her, wearing that, someone who can comment on his transformation as a character."_